# NotInTransactionException while testing spring repository with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

I am having Exception: `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException` while testing a repository.

My Domain class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Question {

    @GraphId Long nodeId;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String id;

    String title;

    public Question(String id, String title) { 
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title; 
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends GraphRepository<Question>,
        NamedIndexRepository<Question> {

    Question findById(String id);
}
```

Question Repository Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/users-test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class QuestionRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired Neo4jOperations template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateQuestion() throws Exception {
        Question question = template.save(new Question("1", "help me"));

        Question foundQuestion = this.questionRepository.findById("1");

        assertEquals("created and found quesion are equal", question, foundQuestion);
    }

}
```

The beans configuration for this: users-test-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.example.domain"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.example.repository"/>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
```

I am a newbie for Neo4J so I could not sort what the problem is? 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the method as transactional in your interface QuestionRepository

```
@Transactional
Question findById(String id);
```